# Sharing data between PAM app and PAM module

Tags: pam

I have a PAM application that makes use of a particular PAM module for authentication chores. My question is, what is the best for the module to share an arbitrary string of bytes with the application?

My understanding of the PAM API is that, in general, the application must use the pam_get_item() call in order to obtain data from the module. However, the item types that can be shared are very limited, and they do not seem to accommodate for what I need - with the possible exception of the PAM_CONV item type. If anybody in this forum has experience with this kind of thing their feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I think I found the answer. In essence, the application has to define a PAM conversation callback in which a pointer to a data buffer is provided. The PAM module has to invoke the callback at the appropriate time, and copy the appropriate data into that buffer. The application will simply obtain the desired data by reading the contents of the buffer.

This will of course have to be carefully choreographed by the application, and the module may have to be modified to invoke the callback at the right time. The idea is simple though.

I am learning a lot as a result of posting to this forum, even if I don't seem to be getting any feedback when it comes to PAM-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [PAM_CONV](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_conv). as it says:

> The PAM library uses an application-defined callback to allow a direct
> communication between a loaded module and the application. This
> callback is specified by the struct pam_conv passed to pam_start(3) at
> the start of the transaction.